# Get info from host and let ansible decide on which host to apply next task

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an ansible playbook that have to **count sub directories** in a path on several hosts and then apply another set of tasks on the host with the lower number of subdirectories.

I can get the count from hosts. But I do not know how go forward.

```yaml
---
- name: Count subdirectories in /var/docker
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Find subdirectories in /var/docker
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: /var/docker
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory
      register: found_dirs

    - name: Count subdirectories
      set_fact:
        subdirectory_count: "{{ found_dirs.files | length }}"

    - name: Display subdirectory count
      debug:
        var: subdirectory_count
```

Can you help me? I'm stuck.

solution example

```yaml
---
- name: Count subdirectories 
  hosts: webprod1,staging1
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  vars:

 

    host_count: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                         zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                             map('extract', hostvars, 'subdirectory_count')|
                             map('int'))) }}"
    host_count_min: "{{ (host_count|dict2items|
                                    sort(attribute='value')|
                                    first).key }}"



  tasks:


    - name: Find subdirectories in /var/docker
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: /var/docker
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory
      register: found_dirs


    - name: Count subdirectories
      set_fact:
        subdirectory_count: "{{ found_dirs.files | length }}"

 

    - name: Display subdirectory count
      debug:
        var: subdirectory_count


    - block:
        - debug:
            var: host_count
        - debug:
            var: host_count_min
      run_once: true

 


    - name: Create an empty file named AAA.txt in /tmp
      file:
        path: /tmp/AAA2.txt
        state: touch
      delegate_to : "{{ host_count_min }}"
```

has context menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the dictionary of the hosts and the values of *subdirectory_count*

```yaml
  host_count: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                       zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                           map('extract', hostvars, 'subdirectory_count')|
                           map('int'))) }}"
```

Convert the dictionary to a list and sort the list by the attribute *value*. Take the attribute *key* from the first item

```yaml
  host_count_min: "{{ (host_count|dict2items|
                                  sort(attribute='value')|
                                  first).key }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 

- hosts: all

  vars:

    host_count: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                         zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                             map('extract', hostvars, 'subdirectory_count')|
                             map('int'))) }}"
    host_count_min: "{{ (host_count|dict2items|
                                    sort(attribute='value')|
                                    first).key }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Set data for testing
      set_fact:
        subdirectory_count: "{{ sc[inventory_hostname] }}"
      vars:
        sc:
          test_11: 5
          test_12: 3
          test_13: 11

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: host_count
        - debug:
            var: host_count_min
      run_once: true

    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: >
              apply another set of tasks on the host
              with the lower number of subdirectories
        - debug:
            msg: task 1
        - debug:
            msg: task 2
        - debug:
            msg: task n
      run_once: true
      delegate_to : "{{ host_count_min }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [Set data for testing] *******************************************************************
ok: [test_13]
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  host_count:
    test_11: 5
    test_13: 11

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  host_count_min: test_11

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    apply another set of tasks on the host with the lower number of subdirectories

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: task 1

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: task 2

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: task n

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution. To be added as the next task in your play.

Some references to understand the below example if needed

- [ansible special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) (check `ansible_play_hosts` and `hostvars`)
- [extracting attributes from a dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables)
- [jinja2 `sort` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.sort)
- [jinja2 `map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map)
- [jinja2 `first` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.first)

```yaml
- name: Run a task only on host with highest number of dirs
  vars:
    my_host: >-
      {{
        ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars)
        | sort(attribute='subdirectory_count')
        | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | first
      }}
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: Run on relevant host
  when: "{{ inventory_hostname == my_host }}"
```

Comment: unfortunaly not working. i get
FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ inventory_hostname == my_host }}' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ inventory_hostname == my_host }}): {{\n  ansible_play_host | map('extract', hostvars)\n  | sort(reverse=true, attribute='subdirectory_count')\n  | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | first\n}}: 'ansible_play_host' is undefined

Comment: The correction was there 30mn ago: `ansible_play_host` => `ansible_play_hosts`. I actually did it fast enough for it not to be visible in the history of the post. And I just fixed the reverse order which is not needed since you want the lowest number of dirs. My bad.